# Default Stack not correct while using AWS CDK typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I wanted to confirm if the default stack VPC generated by cdk in ./lib is correct.
Here are my steps -

```
%% cdk --version
1.83.0 (build 827c5f4)
%% tsc --version
Version 4.1.3
mkdir vpc
cd vpc 
cdk init app --language=typescript
```

Now, if I look at the file ./lib/vpc-stack.ts

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';

export class VpcStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here
  }
}
```

However, the file should have been ( I think)

```
//vpc-stack.ts
import {App, Stack, StackProps} from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {Peer, Port, SecurityGroup, SubnetType, Vpc} from '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2'

export class VpcStack extends Stack {
    readonly vpc: Vpc;
    readonly ingressSecurityGroup: SecurityGroup;
    readonly egressSecurityGroup: SecurityGroup;

    constructor(scope: App, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        //Place resource definitions here.
    }
}
```

Really appreciate if anyone could point the missing step.

Thanks !

Comment: Really appreciate if anyone could take a look at this one. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`app` template creates an empty stack definition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html#cli-init

```
TEMPLATE is an optional template. If the desired template is app, the default, you may omit it. The available templates are:

Template | Description
app (default) | Creates an empty AWS CDK app.
sample-app | Creates an AWS CDK app with a stack containing an Amazon SQS queue and an Amazon SNS topic.

The templates use the name of the project folder to generate names for files and classes inside your new app.
```

The stack definition without resources is the expected command output.

Comment: Thanks Milan. Is there a way to generate a default VPC CDK ?

Comment: The default VPC is currently generated for you automatically - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#default-vpc-components

You can reference the VPC in your CDK scripts by looking it up e.g. by the VPC ID - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#static-fromwbrlookupscope-id-options

Alternatively, you can create your custom VPC in the CDK if you wish.